# Linux Mint shortcuts not working

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I'm trying to set up a simple "Ctrl+Shift+Escape" shortcut to open the system monitor. I've read the correct command would be "gnome-system-monitor". If I run this command on the terminal, it does open the system monitor as expected. However, when I set the shortcut, it doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: On older versions of Ubuntu, and perhaps Mint, the Esc key does not seem to work in shortcuts. As of Ubuntu 18.04,, I find it can, and use that same key combination as for Windows Task Manager. It might also be the move from Unity to Gnome, though, that allowed it.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add, this is Linux Mint 20, based on Ubuntu 20. It has the Cinnamon desktop which is based on Gnome I believe. I tried to set it to "Alt+S" (just for testing purposes, not that I actually want to set it to that) and it didn't work either.